# Deploy customized Node.js module on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, drupal, deployment

I have installed the `drupal-node.js` module by running `npm install` command. And then I go inside `drupal-node.js` in `node_modules` folder and done place another module inside it.

To run my above Node.js app, I have to go inside `node_modules` folder and in `drupal-node.js` and I run `node app.js`.

Now, I have to deploy my above Node.js app to Heroku. But I think Heroku doesn't allow us to make changes in the `node_modules/` folder.

How can I use my local update on Heroku?

Comment: "And then I go inside `drupal-node.js` in `node_modules` folder and done place another module inside it."—why?

Comment: Also, why are you running `node app.js` from inside `node_modules`?

Comment: @Chris, I already told that I have to done some customization inside the contrib module to make it working for me.

Comment: So If you know the answer, Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a single situation where you should be directly modifying anything in `node_modules/`. If you really need to modify a library, submit your change to the library maintainers.

If that's not an option for whatever reason, fork the library and install from your fork using `yarn` or `npm`.

Forking a library shouldn't be done lightly. By doing this you're adding a maintenance burden to your project. Now, in addition to your own code, you need to maintain your fork. Pulling updates in from upstream so you can take advantage of bug fixes and security updates is important.