# How to deploy local node_modules folder onto heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have done some changes inside `node_modules` folder inside a module and run NPM install again inside a module in node_modules. It's working fine on local.

Now, I want to deploy it on Heroku. **But Heroku looks at the package.json file and installs all the NPM modules again**.

So, Please let me know "How can I deploy local node_modules folder onto Heroku" and prevent Heroku to NPM install again.

Comment: Easier way: fork the module you are modifying, and point your `package.json` to your version instead. You can do it even with [private repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23210437/npm-install-private-github-repositories-by-dependency-in-package-json).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @Amadan. Can you please provide any reference for that?

Comment: I did. That's what the link was for. Unless you're asking how to fork a repository...?

Comment: Find the repository of the package on GitHub using `npm view <packagename> repository.url`. Use [GitHub Help on forking](https://help.github.com/en/articles/fork-a-repo) to perform the fork. Then you'll need to `checkout` the fork, make your changes, `add` and `commit` them, and `push` them back to GitHub (the relevant help pages are easy to find, and knowing how to use Git is super-useful for any programmer these days anyway).

Comment: Secrets like credentials belong in environment variables, not in committed code.

Comment: So, Will my fork be publicly available to anyone?

Comment: If you set it to public, yes. If you set it to private, no. Again, see my first link to see how to link a private repository. However, again, things like credentials do not belong in code, and should not be committed, private repo or not.

Comment: @Amadan, Please let me know "Can I set the custom url for a npm package" inside package.json?

Comment: Seriously, for the third time, there's examples for that in the link in my first comment here.

Comment: Sorry I read it now.

Comment: Last thing, I am creating a Public repo so that I can provide the link in package.json, So do i need to push node_modules folder onto repo?

Comment: OP, is this also you? https://stackoverflow.com/users/9417293/rajat Why are you using multiple accounts? You seem to be asking the same thing over and over with at least two accounts, and I [already provided an answer at least once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55617204/354577). Please don't ask the same question many times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploy customized Node.js module on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55610759/deploy-customized-node-js-module-on-heroku)

Comment: @Chris, No I am only using one account..

Comment: @test, strange, since you comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55625558/354577) as if you're [Rajat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9417293/rajat).

Comment: I think username on SO can be same.