# How to give a custom url in package.json for a package

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, node-modules, package.json

I have done customization in a `npm package` inside `node_modules` folder. Now I want to **deploy it on heroku**. But what heroku does is It will see the package.json and **install the fresh package**.

So someone suggested me to provide the **custom url for a npm package**, So that Heroku will download the npm package from this custom url not from npm.

How can I achieve the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm install private github repositories by dependency in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23210437/npm-install-private-github-repositories-by-dependency-in-package-json)

Answer (score 3):

You should fork this package, make customization on your fork and install your version as a project dependency `npm install <git repo url>`

1. find package that you want to customise on github
2. use fork button to fork it to your repositories
3. make customization on this new repo created in step 2
4. run `npm install` with url address to your repository

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Can you please provide a step by step reference for that?

Comment: That's great. I will check and let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: I have forked library and use git clone to copy the forked repo at my computer and done the customizations.

Comment: Please let me know, what should I do next?

Comment: push changes to your repo, and then use your repo url during npm install

Comment: I pushed my changes to repo. Below is my repo url: https://github.com/rajatlnweb/drupal-nodejs

Comment: My npm module name is drupal-node.js. Can you please tell me "How can i specify the repo url inside package.json?

Comment: run `npm install https://github.com/rajatlnweb/drupal-nodejs.git`, and in `package.json` ther wiil be `"drupal-node.js": "git+https://github.com/rajatlnweb/drupal-nodejs.git"`

Comment: Should I need to run "npm install https://github.com/rajatlnweb/drupal-nodejs.git" on server root? As I am using so many dependencies in my project.

Comment: can't I specify the "drupal-node.js" : "git+https://github.com/rajatlnweb/drupal-nodejs.git" directly in package.json and run npm install directly at server root?

Comment: I am getting error: " Could not install from "git+github.com\rajatlnweb\drupal-nodejs.git" as it does not contain a package.json file".

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by the end. Yes you can put this directly in packae.json and then after running npm install, every dependencies will be downloaded

Comment: okay, Trying it. Will let you know if got any error in 2 minutes.

Comment: Sir, I created a new package.json file and in dependencies I placed "drupal-node.js" : "git+https://github.com/rajatlnweb/drupal-nodejs.git"

Comment: And when I hit "npm install". It's giving error "couldn't install from repo as it doesn't contain a package.json file"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191637/discussion-between-lukasz-szewczak-and-rajat).